# Merge content of several pdf documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, whitespace

I get lot's of stamp-documents like this every day:

[image: stamp-doc]

There is lot's of white space under every stamp. If I print them, that cost's lots of paper, so I want to merge the content of several documents into one pdf-document. So that I can place like 8 stamps on into one document and just have to print one page instead of 8.

I want to solve this problem with javascript (or node.js) and I've already found some pdf-libraries, but these libraries just let me copy whole pages and don't eliminate the white-space.

Are there any suggestions?

I also thought about converting the pdf to png or jpeg and cut the whitespace of the image, but I don't if that's possible.

I would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Another option is to convert your file into word and follow this guide: https://www.consultdmw.com/removing-unwanted-spaces-in-word-documents.html

Comment: To crop out white space in JavaScript, you can look into using the [HTML Canvas](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/javascript/javascript-crop-image/). If you have the option of using server side code, you could also consider using a specialized toolkit like the LEADTOOLS Image Processing library, which includes an [AutoCropRectangleCommand](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t12791-) .NET class which can be implemented in a service. In addition, you could use the barcode features to assist with determining the cropping bounds. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the LEADTOOLS vendor)